# Ensure package-scope fixture stays alive until all package tests are complete

Tags: python, pytest

I have weird behavior when running tests using pytest. I'm running tests in the `tests/` folder, and I have a subpackage `tests/foo/` that contains a package-scope fixture `bar()`. Additionally, foo has a parametrized package-scope fixture `baz(bar)`, that depends on `bar`, with two parameters, say A and B. Typically, tests in `foo` get executed once for `baz` with A, then for `baz` with B. It is important that `bar` only gets setup once for the entire test suite, and it worked well until now.

What happened now is I added a new test file directly in the `tests/` folder, say `test_frub.py`, that contains 1 test which does not depend on any fixtures. Now the test order is:

1. tests with `baz` with A
2. `test_frub.py`
3. tests with `baz` with B.

Because `test_frub.py` is in the middle, `bar` gets torn down and setup again, breaking the test flow. The contents of `test_frub.py` do not seem to matter. What is weird is that besides `test_frub.py` there are other modules in the main `tests/` folder that do not seem to cause this issue.

Diagram:

```
tests/
- foo/
  - conftest.py
  - test_table.py
  - test_door.py
  - ...
- test_qux.py
- ...
- test_frub.py <- this file causes the problem
```

`tests/foo/conftest.py` contains:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="package")
def bar():
    # setup
    yield
    # teardown

@pytest.fixture(scope="package", params=["A", "B"])
def baz(bar):
    # setup
    yield
    # teardown
```

Is there a fix for this, other than making `bar` session-scoped?